# PHP regex preg_replace function Joomla! plugin

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I want to create  plugin that finds and replaces phone numbers with a linked number for mobile. This is a php function that I have written for Joomla to use to replace a phone number...

```
protected function clickToCall(&$text, &$params){
    // phone number pattern...
    $pattern = '~(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}~';
    //replacement pattern...
    $replacement = '<a href="tel:$1$2">$1$2</a>';
    //use preg_replace to actually replace the pattern
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
    //return the new value
    return true;
}
```

Right now the function finds the pattern and just replaces it with an empty link. How can insert the phone number found by regex into a link?

Comment: Try replacing `'<a href="tel:$1$2">$1$2</a>'` with `'<a href="tel:$0">$0</a>'`. Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/YUVXNm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `$1` and `$2` backreferences that refer to Group 1 (i.e. substring captured with `(\+0?1\s)?`) and non-existent Group 2 (thus, it is an empty string) rather than to the whole match (that can be referred to with the help of `$0` or `\0`).

Here is a fix:

```
$text = 'Phone +1 (234) 345 6543 to obtain a free copy.';
$pattern = '~(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}~';
$replacement = '<a href="tel:$0">$0</a>';
echo $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YUVXNm)

See more about [*Back references*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php#regexp.reference.back-references) in [PHP  Manual](http://php.net/).

Comment: This is awesome! I guess had a poor understanding of what the ( ) and how to use the $1$2 etc because  I'm not very familiar with regex, Thank you for taking the time to answer this, this was a huge help.